# Bit count in the following case

Tags: c++

I got the following questions in one of the interviews plz help me some ideas to solve it as am completely unaware how to proceed

A non-empty array A of N elements contains octal representation of a non-negative integer K, i.e. each element of A belongs to the interval [0; 7]

Write a function:

```
int bitcount_in_big_octal(const vector<int> &A);
```

that returns the number of bits set to 1 in the binary representation of K. The function should return -1 if the number of bits set to 1 exceeds 10,000,000.

Assume that the array can be very large.

Assume that N is an integer within the range [1..100,000].

Comment: What have you tried so far? And also, that's a C++ function prototype, not Java.

Answer (score 2):

is there any time restriction?
I have one idea: at first, make the following dictionary, {0->0, 1->1, 2->1, 3-> 2, 4->1, 5->1, 6->2, 7->3}. then, loop the array A to sum the 1s in every elements using the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over your representation
2. for-each element in that iterate, convert the representation to its number of bits.  @meteorgan's answer is a great way to do just that.  If you need the representation for something other than bit counts, you'll probably want to convert it to some intermediate form useful for whatever else you'll be using - e.g. to `byte[]`: each octet in the representation should correspond to a single `byte` and since all you're doing is counting bits it doesn't matter that Java's byte is signed.  then for-each `byte` in the array, use an existing bit counting [lib](http://mandala.co.uk/java/bitutils/BitUtils.java), cast the `byte` to an `int` and use `Integer.bitCount(...)`, or roll your own, etc - to count the bits
3. add the result to a running total, escape the iteration if you hit your threshold.

That's a Java answer in the details (like the lib I linked), but the algorithm steps are fine for C++, find a replacement library (or use the dictionary answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using the indexed (dictionary) based approach.

```
INDEX = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3]

def bitcount_in_big_octal(A):
    counter = 0
    for octal in A: counter += INDEX[octal]
    return counter
```